# Conservation of Momentum and The Expansion of The Universe

Tags: cosmology, momentum, conservation-laws, space-expansion, redshift

As I understand it, the cosmological red shifting of light is one of the effects of the expansion of the universe. But as the wavelength of light increases, the momentum given by:

p = $\frac{h}{\lambda}$

decreases. I'm curious as to how this loss of momentum is accounted for.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7060/  (bearing in mind that for a photon $E=|p|c$).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshifting of Light and the expansion of the universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7060/)

Comment: Not the same as the previous. He's asking about momentum, not energy. There are 3 spacelike isometries in cosmology, i.e., space is symmetric. It is not like energy, there is no timelike symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

For photons , with the velocity of light c=1, E=p . As the energy is decreasing due to the relativistic [doppler effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/reldop2.html) the momentum will be decreasing proportionately. In a flat space the momentum balance will be kept by the receding star/galaxy.

The whole deal of conservation laws in general relativity is quite complicated, and theorists get creative. See this [link for example](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/energy_gr.html)

For:

> Expansion of the universe leading to cosmological redshift
>
> Cosmologists model the expanding universe with Friedmann-Robertson-Walker (FRW) spacetimes.  (The familiar "expanding balloon speckled with galaxies" belongs to this class of models.) The FRW spacetimes are neither static nor asymptotically flat.  Those who harbor no qualms about pseudo-tensors will say that radiant energy becomes gravitational energy.  Others will say that the energy is simply lost.

The same "confusion" will exist for momentum conservation.