# When light gets red shifted by the expending universe it's energy decreases. What happens to that energy?

Tags: cosmology, photons, energy-conservation, space-expansion, redshift

If a Photon of light is red shifted its wavelength increases and therefore its energy decreases. What happens to that energy as energy should be conserved right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redshifting of Light and the expansion of the universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7060/)