# Space expansion effect on wavelengths across two points in space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, space-expansion

Is the expansion of space taken into consideration when calculating light or any (Radio to Gamma) wave length distance and speed? I know C is a constant, but my concern is if "space expansion" is somehow altering the speed of light or any other wave length relative between two points.

Comment: Think of cosmic background radiation. Now a some Kelvin blackbody radiation, it was "born" as a some thousand Kelvin radiation, when protons and electrons joined to hydrogen atoms in the young kosmos.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the number of wavelengths of light spanning a distance invarient with respect to spacetime distortion?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15834/is-the-number-of-wavelengths-of-light-spanning-a-distance-invarient-with-respect)

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15834/is-the-number-of-wavelengths-of-light-spanning-a-distance-invarient-with-respect).  I would say that it depends on what the application is.  In astronomy, typically the answer is yes.  In radio broadcasting, no.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which this would occur is that a photon emitted by A would be recieved by B at some later time, when B had cosmologically accelerated away from A, so it would see a redshifted wavelength. In terms of a local description, the expansion of space is *entirely* contained in the local relative motions of objects, so that if two things are relatively stationary, there will be no additional wavelength change as light propagates between them.

When they are far away on a cosmological scale, at least one of these two relatively stationary things will seem to be moving relative to the cosmological idea of being at rest (no redshift in the microwave background).

It is incorrect to impute the redshift of light to an expansion of space *over and above* the relative motion of emitter and reciever. The expansion of space just tells you how different rest frames far away are related.